# Does do_div() in Linux work in 32 and 64 bit architectures?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel, integer-division

I need to do an integer division in a kernel module and I am using do_div() for that. It seems to work on my machine (I have an i686 processor), however I am not sure that it works everywhere. Could anyone confirm whether `do_div()` should function correctly in 32 bit and 64 bit architectures, or whether there are any know limitations ?

I use Ubuntu 10.04 with kernel 2.6.38, so I am interested in support for kernels >= 2.6.38.

I would also be interested if anyone knows a better way to do an integer division in the kernel than `do_div()`.

Best Regards

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`do_div()` does work on 64bit arch, but unless you really need the remainder and is fully aware of the effects of using `do_div()`, you should probably be doing bit shifts instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Then I understand that do_div() should always work regardless of the architecture, correct ? Regarding doing bit shifts, that would only be possible if I wanted to divide by a power of 2, right? This is not my case since I need to divide by any integer.